# Generating a random array index?

Tags: c++

I have a `std::vector<int>` for enabled cards.
I want the computer to choose one at random:

```
int r = 0;
r = rand() % m_enabledCards.size();
cardCount.push_back(m_enabledCards[r]);
```

For some reason this returns an index that is out of bounds and the vector has around 13 elements.

What could be wrong?

Thanks

Comment: What convinced you that the index is out of bounds?

Comment: "What could be wrong?"  Something you haven't shown us.  Try running your program under valgrind, and also use m_enabledCards.at(r) to make it throw if it does somehow get an out-of-bounds index.

Comment: There is no error in this code snippet. The problem must be somewhere else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I can't see anything wrong with the code you posted, the error should be somewhere else, unless I overlooked something. Maybe your `m_enabledCards` vector is actually empty? Though that should give a "division by zero" error for the modulus line, I can't think of any other reason with the given code.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's because of a conflict of types (`size()` returns an `unsigned int`).
Try casting `size()` as an int or save it in an int variable:

```
int my_size = m_enabledCards.size();
r = rand() % my_size;
```

If that still doesn't work, try printing the `rand()` value.

Comment: size() probably returns a size_t, not unsigned int.  On 32-bit systems they are likely the same; on 64-bit likely not.

Comment: @John, `size()` returns a `size_type`, that is an unsigned integral type, according to: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/vector/size/

Comment: Sure, but that type is often actually size_t, not "unsigned int" as you said (`unsigned int` is not the same as "an unsigned integral type").